# How to pass variables dynamically in svg file?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xaml, svg, uwp

I am working in a UWP project, and my intention is to get inputs(coordinates) from the user via a textbox and provide that inputs to a svg file , so that the size of svg image can change according to user's need.
Do you know how it can be done ?

Comment: Do you need to change the contents of the Svg file or just its display size? If you only need to change the display size, you can modify the `Width` / `Height` property of the display control (such as `Image`).

Comment: Hi Richard , thanks for your reply , and sorry I couldn't reply earlier. I want to change the contents of svg file because that will allow me to change the orientation of the figure. Is there any way to change the orientation as well as size of svg image without changing the contents of svg file , dynamically?

Comment: Yes, we can use `RenderTransform` to transform the `Image` control. This transformation just visual layer. This is the relevant [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/transforms).